# usage of autofac compared with a simple IoC implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am currently using/experimenting with autofac as my IoC controller.

Previously to this I used a simple static class defining two methods, similar to

```
public static TService Resolve<TService>()  
public static void Register<IType, ImpType>()
```

where ImpType must be of IType.

Now over to autofac. When registering, you might do something like

```
builder.RegisterType<ProductRepository>().As<IProductRepository>();
```

however if ProductRepository is-not-a IProductRepository you don't get a compile error?
Is there some way of wiring things up more safely if desired?

Secondly, when building my Ioc modules I use something like

```
public static class IoCContainer
{
    public static IContainer BaseContainer { get; private set; }

    public static void Build(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        BaseContainer = builder.Build();            
    }
}
```

After I have called IoCContainer.Build(..) I can no longer register anything 'into' the BaseContainer. Compare this with the simple model where you can register anything from anywhere. Perhaps this is by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `.RegisterType<Foo>.As<IFoo>` pattern is not type safe simply because the C# compiler (or the CLR type system) does not handle such type constraints. For example, the following hypothetical declaration of the `As` method won't compile:

```
interface IRegistration<TImplementation>
{
   void As<TContract>() where TImplementation : TContract;
}
```

The compiler error is "'SomeNamespace.IRegistration.As()' does not define type parameter 'TImplementation'".

> Is there some way of wiring things up more safely if desired?

The following seems to work (though it is discouraged by the [best practices](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/BestPractices) section on the Autofac wiki). It will give a compiler error unless `Foo` implements `IFoo`:

```
     var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
     builder.Register<IFoo>(c => new Foo()).SingleInstance();

     var container = builder.Build();
     var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

`c` is the `IComponentContext`. If the `Foo` constructor requires a constructor argument then you can write `c => new Foo(c.Resolve<IBar>())`.

> After I have called IoCContainer.Build(..) I can no longer register anything 'into' the BaseContainer

You can [update the container](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/05/autofac-2-2-released/) in Autofac 2.2.

Comment: Thanks. Even after reading thru that link I don't really appreciate the difference between builder.Register(c => new Foo()).As<IFoo>(); and builder.Register<IFoo>(c => new Foo()); The latter appears superior as it is type safe whereas the former is not. Not sure why the former does not type check?

Comment: @wal: I have added a possible explanation for the fact that the `.As` method does not check the type.

Comment: I have also posted a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095575/constrain-type-parameter-of-a-method-to-the-interfaces-implemented-by-another-typ

Comment: Cheers. Its not as bad as I originally thought because the runtime error occurs when you called Build() as opposed to when you lookup the service. However I reckon its a bad tradeoff (to lose the type safeness)