# Constrain type parameter of a method to the interfaces implemented by another type

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

The intention of the following is to only allow the call `IRegistration<Foo>.As<IFoo>` if `Foo` implements `IFoo`:

```
interface IRegistration<TImplementation>
{
   void As<TContract>() where TImplementation : TContract;
}
```

This is not allowed by the C# 3.0 compiler. I get the following error:

> 'SomeNamespace.IRegistration.As()' does not define type 
>   parameter 'TImplementation'

Is there some way around this, other than putting both type parameters in the method declaration?

This question is inspired by this [other question about Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077362/usage-of-autofac-compared-with-a-simple-ioc-implementation/4088749).

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add a constraint on a type parameter that does not exist in the type parameter list.

Is this what you meant?

```
interface IRegistration<TImplementation> where TImplementation : TContract
{
   void As<TContract>();
}
```

Though this will not compile either - you can't have a generic constraint on a generic type.

This will compile, though will probably not produce the constraint you want on the method itself:

```
interface IRegistration<TImplementation,TContract> where TImplementation : TContract
{
   void As<TContract>();
}
```

See if this will do:

```
interface IRegistration<TImplementation,TContract> where TImplementation : TContract
{
   void As();
}
```

This way, any time you use `TImplementation`, it will be constrained to be a `TContract` and you can still use `TContract` in the `As` method.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) - look at the section towards the end of the page, titled "Type Parameters as Constraints".

Comment: Hmm, don't think this works - `TContract` on the interface is different from `TContract` on the method.

Comment: @Tim Robinson - good point. I was looking for something that will compile and forgot about the requirements... Answer updated.

Comment: Agree with your updated answer - I can't think of any other way around this.

Comment: I'm aware that there is no problem if the type parameters are declared together (both on the interface or both on the method) - that's not what I am interested in. To clarify I have added a link to the question that inspired this one. The correct answer to my question is probably a simple "no, you can't do that" but I asked anyway in case I missed something.

Comment: @Wim Coenen - That's would be the answer... this is not something that will give you compile time type checks. I suspect that Autofac does some reflection during runtime to achieve type safety.